# Mapear uma propriedade como enum

Tags: c#, automapper

Estou começando os estudos de automapper então nem sei se estou usando os termos corretos para fazer a pergunta, mas é o seguinte.
Tenho a classe Paciente que dentre outras propriedades, tem um enum chamado Estado, que como vcs podem presumir, são os estados do Brasil. No banco, a tabela paciente guarda na coluna estado um int com o código do enum que representa o estado.

```
  public class Paciente
  {
     public Estado Estado { get; set; }
  }
```

Usando o automapper, criei o método

```
private readonly IBaseService<Paciente> _service;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

  public async Task<IEnumerable<PacienteViewModel>> GetAsync()
    {
        var pacientes = await _service.GetAsync();
        var result = pacientes.Select(t => _mapper.Map<Paciente, PacienteViewModel>(t)).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

Mas chamando este método dá o seguinte erro:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'.

Que suspeito que seja por causa desse enum, mas não tenho certeza, nem ideia do que fazer pra testar.

Comment: Propriedade Estado da sua PacienteViewModel é uma string?

Comment: Como está definido o seu enum e o que você está postando para a controller, o enumerador ou o displayname?

Comment: @MarcosJunior é o mesmo enum

Comment: @LeandroAngelo o enum está com displayname, mas nesse primeiro momento nem estou usando ele. Por isso desconfio que o automapper não está convertendo o código dele pra mapear

Comment: A mensagem de erro diz que você está postando uma string em uma propriedade que espera um int

Answer (score 0):

Paciente e PacienteViewModel devem ter os mesmos tipos de dados, ou então, você deve informar a conversão manualmente.

```
 .ForMember(dest => dest.Estado, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (EstadoEnum)src.Estado))
```